# Trying to find google/protobuf/compiler/parser.h

Tags: compiling, source

We have an application currently building on Fedora that we're trying to port to Xenial (16.04). It makes use of a header file

```
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.h
```

that in the Fedora world we find in the protobuf-devel rpm.

However, we've installed just about every apt we can find around protobuf, and it's still not appeared - any idea where we can find this fiie in Ubuntu?

output from sudo apt list | grep protob

```
golang-gogoprotobuf-dev/xenial 0.0~git20150828.0.6cab0cc-1 amd64
golang-goprotobuf-dev/xenial 0.0~git20150526-2 amd64
golang-protobuf-extensions-dev/xenial,xenial 0+git20150513.fc2b8d3-3 all
libactivemq-protobuf-java/xenial,xenial 1.1-4 all
libactivemq-protobuf-java-doc/xenial,xenial 1.1-4 all
libmirprotobuf3/xenial-updates 0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.21.0+16.04.20160330-0ubuntu1]
libprotobuf-c-dev/xenial,now 1.2.1-1 amd64 [installed]
libprotobuf-c1/xenial,now 1.2.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libprotobuf-c1-dbg/xenial 1.2.1-1 amd64
libprotobuf-dev/xenial,now 2.6.1-1.3 amd64 [installed]
libprotobuf-java/xenial,xenial 2.6.1-1.3 all
libprotobuf-lite9v5/xenial,now 2.6.1-1.3 amd64 [installed]
libprotobuf9v5/xenial,now 2.6.1-1.3 amd64 [installed]
protobuf-c-compiler/xenial,now 1.2.1-1 amd64 [installed]
protobuf-compiler/xenial,now 2.6.1-1.3 amd64 [installed]
python-protobuf/xenial 2.6.1-1.3 amd64
python-protobuf.socketrpc/xenial,xenial 1.3.2-3 all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libprotoc-dev/filelist

```
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_generator.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_generator.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.h
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
/usr/include/google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotoc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotoc.so
/usr/share/doc/libprotoc-dev
```

So that would be `libprotoc-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to grab the latest [Protocol Buffers code from github.](https://github.com/google/protobuf)

If you just want just that specific file it's [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/find/master)